# Store date-time as integer in sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am trying to convert a date-time string value into an integer when I store it in a sqlite table. I am using Python (Flask). I am getting an 'Error in insert operation' with the following query.

Any ideas?

```
with sql.connect("flaskjournal.db") as con:
cur = con.cursor()
t_i = strftime('%s','time_in')
cur.execute("INSERT INTO entries (beach, board, swell, wind, score, notes, time_in) 
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",(beach, board, swell, wind, score, notes, t_i))
con.commit()
msg = "Record successfully added"
```

Comment: Did you try to print all your variable just before the INSERT?  Do they all look correct?

Comment: Thanks for your help, got this solved a different way by doing the conversion in python code above this statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the timestamp instead.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = int(time.mktime(datetime_object.timetuple())
```

Comment: Thanks...this made me thinking of doing the conversion in python code above the sqlite stuff.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Make `t_i` insert a unix timestamp via your create table schema. so you don't need to muck with it from python.

```
sqlite> create table t1 (
  ...> id integer primary key,
  ...> time t_i default (strftime('%s', 'now')),
  ...> txt text);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help...used a different approach but got this working.